# In which file of the Linux registry (/var/log) is access to /etc/shadow stored?

Tags: permissions, syslog, rsyslog

I tried to `cat`, using a non-root user, the `/etc/shadow` file. Access has been denied due to lack of permissions, but here's the thing:

In which file in the Linux registry (`/var/log`) is this attempt to access `/etc/shadow` stored? I have been looking for it, but I am unable to find it.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it *is* stored - at least not by default; `cat` just receives an `EACCES` (Permission denied) return value from the `openat` system call, and writes the corresponding message to standard error.

Comment: It's not stored. EACESS is a program-level error (as opposed to a system-level error), so the program MAY log it. EACCESS is so common that logging it is unhelpful.